# Access xampp outside localhost

Tags: windows-server-2008, port, url, xampp

I have created a xampp page on Windows server 2008. I am successfully able to load the xampp page and other php pages that I have created using localhost:8080/.

Firstly : I want to know how can I access the xampp page from outside the local machine via some other computer connected through internet.

Secondly : Can I use my server name (54.243.xxx.xxx) in place of localhost in the url to access the xampp page and other files. 54.243.xxx.xxx:8080/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on your **Listen** option in the **httpd.conf** / **httpd-ssl.conf**.
If it is set to

> 127.0.0.1:8080

apache will only listen and serve requests to that IP address. If there's only a statement present like

> Listen 8080

it will listen on all interfaces by default and you will be able to reach your page by using your public IP address and the port number.

Comment: Thanks. Also I found my port was blocked by ISP which i made unblocked.